Problem Using Image Textures as Alpha Masks in Blender
I have in total three image in 1st image letter 'A' in black color and thebackgroundin white and the 2nd image letter 'A' in white color and thebackgroundin black color and a third image a png image with transparentbackgroundthat has a arrow in it .
Now I connected the third image color output to the base color input of the BSD's and the the alpha to BSDF's alpha which gave the results and now when I wanted to connect the first two image and use it as alpha only when in connect the image textures color output to the BSDF's alpha input I can see the result
Why is that?
Link to the file


You'll greatly increase your chances to get an answer if you take the time to show us not only your textures but also you nodes, or even pack the textures and share your blend file : https://blend-exchange.com/.

Colored or RGB images are made out of 3 Black and White or BW channels, describing how much of each primary color (Red, Green, Blue) is in each pixel:

BW images are made either out of one channel marked as BW, or the three RGB channels, but then wasting disk size defining color on three channels instead of one.
Alpha is an additional BW channel that is specifically marked as alpha and is interpreted as telling how opaque a pixel is via values from 0 to 1, with 1 being opaque.
Some image formats can carry the alpha channel alongside the RGB channels (like png or exr), making these images RGBA:

But some formats can't do that, require the user to carry it as a separate BW image (one channel). And sometimes people intentionally carry the alpha data in a separate file, even if they use a format that doesn't require it.
If you plug an RGB image into the Principled BSDF's alpha input, it will use the combined luminance of the RGB channels (essentially reading a colored image as a BW one), which rarely looks good if not meant to be:

Whereas, a BW image (or the alpha channel of an RGBA image) will be read as is.

In Blender, an image texture node have two outputs: color and alpha.
While the color output is your regular image color output as RGB data regardless of the source image having RGB channels or just one BW channel, the alpha output specifically gives you the dedicated alpha data if the is one, or just outputs pure white.
In other words, Blender can't tell that a BW image is a standalone alpha data. After all, how could it tell the difference between that and a regular BW image?

Hence, the image you use in your second screenshot being just a regular BW image which you happen to use as alpha in your shader, you still need to use its color socket, and not the alpha.

May i know what is happening here in the other two images like how when color socket is connected to alpha input it is giving transparent results .How is the blender handling this

RGB images are made out of 3 BW channels describing how much of each primary color is in each pixel. Alpha is a BW channel that tells how opaque a pixel is via values from 0 to 1 with 1 being opaque. Some image formats can carry the alpha channel alongside the rgb channels (like png or exr, making them RGBA), and some don't, and require the user to carry it as a separate BW image (one channel). If you plug an RGB image into the Principled BSDF's alpha input, it will use the combined luminance of the RGB channels. Whereas a BW image (or the alpha channel of an RGBA image) will be read as is.
